# Why are there outlying towns/cities on the walls in Shingeki no Kyoujin?

Tags: attack-on-titan

For example, this here:

[image]

Why does it need to jut out of the walls instead of just being inside the walls to begin with?

Comment: Yeah the people that live there are basically bait, so they dont just attack the main wall, its in the manga.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is explained in manga Chapter 2 afterwords.

[image: Wall and district]

You should realize, that walls are long. I mean, *really* long. And it is impossible even to watch over wall, not to mention protecting it. So such districts do exist, to attract all titans attention, since it is much easier to protect small district than miles of wall.

Comment: And I assume the reason that the city isn't simply placed just inside the wall (at the edge) is so that in case the outer wall is breached the main wall isn't compromised.

Answer (score 6):

This is explained at the beginning of episode 2:

> So-called outlier districts like Shiganshina jut out like thorns at vital spots along Wall Maria. Their basic function is to streamline troop dispersal and keep security costs down by drawing titans into specific areas. The calculated design flaw in outlier districts is that they have only a single gate through which its citizens are able to retreat deeper inwards, should the need arise.

Since the walls are rather long, defending them in their entirety is difficult and costly. With the presence of the outlier districts, the titans will be drawn to these districts and will be less inclined to attack the wall at random. (This is because they are attracted to humans, and there is a greater population density at these specific parts of the wall). The defense against the titans can then be focused in these areas, becoming easier and more effective.

Comment: I am also only familiar with SnK up to the end of the anime (although I've also skimmed through a lot of the manga after that section before), so I am not going to know if any later developments would make for a deeper answer.

Comment: I have read the Manga up to date and this is the only explanation. Further revelations about the titans did nothing to change this logic.

Answer (score 2):

There's also to consider that a door is a weak point in the wall, so it needs additional protection from attacks; the city does exactly that, provide an extra layer of protection and acts as a cushion and a pen, to contain and dispatch giants more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Since this has been troublesome for many to understand- I will provide an explanation. The towns are there to keep the titans at bay- giving soldiers something to grapple onto. The towns also have Cannon defense, which will be fine for help. However, if you look onto the picture on the LEFT SIDE, you will see titans approaching the wall. The DISTRICT more or less attracts the titans keeping them away from Shiganshina.